# ASP.NET End point 404 on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

Been using Visual Studio 2019 & ASP.Net. Got all my endpoints working during the development. When deployed on IIS, all my endpoints return 404. While looking at the logs, I get a "404 0 2" error.
I can browse to all pages fine, just the end points not working. I have tried adding various things to my Web.Config all with the same result.

Is a 2019 Server with the latest version of IIS. 
Any help is appreciated. Guessing something is setup wrong on IIS?

The endpoints are done in using a controller, sample code below:

```
        [Route("~/api/students/getyear/{yearid}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetYear(int yearid)
        {
            return await _context.Student.Where(x => x.yearid == yearid).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Called by using

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

When debugging it, I can reach it from "https://localhost:5001/api/students/getyear/0" and when trying on my IIS using "intranet.domain.co.uk/studentnotices/api/students/getyear/0" I get the 404 error

I publish the code to the release folder and copy it to my IIS. Have also tried publishing directly to the IIS but same result

Comment: So you're getting a 404 hitting some mysterious "endpoints". What are these endpoints? Are they controllers? Web Forms pages? What configuration was involved in setting them up? You need to add more detail to your question describing the context.

Comment: Edited. Hope it's better

Answer (score 0):

The win32-staus has already indicated that "The system cannot find the file specified."

So I think your IIS is trying to execute the URL from physical path.
It might because your static file handler is taking over the request instead of asp.net extensionless handler.

Please install IIS asp.net extension feature in turn windows features on or off.  For .net core ,application, please ensure asp.net core web hosting bundle has been installed.